# Does dispatching of action runs in the background of react flow?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

Can anyone please help me in understanding that if I have a component and suppose in **constructor** I dispatched an action, then two scenarios are possible

1. action gets dispatched, and our component becomes ideal, means other lifecycle hooks won't get executed until the action is done. **or**
2. action get dispatched in, our component goes on through other hooks quietly and wait for the props to change

which one is the case?

> In short, actions are dispatched in the background or our component wait until the action is done.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

constructors are not async in nature

> action get dispatched in , our component goes on through other hooks
>   quietly and wait for the props to change

So this is the correct statement.

The action will be dispatched and other life-cycle methods will be triggered.

Check out this code sample with `setTimeout`

See how the other lifecycles trigger in an async manner.

https://codesandbox.io/s/patient-sea-pkyes

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

export default class Test extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    console.log("made");
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log("wait");
    }, 3000);
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    console.log("mount");
  }
  render() {
    return <div>Test</div>;
  }
}
```

This is how `dispatch` would work.

Hope that answers your question:)

Comment: Thanks for answer, so should i assume that action disaptching is like a HTTP request where we wont wait for the response , but continue anyways.?

Answer (score 0):

It depends. If there are no solid changes occurs on props/state(what is a solid change might be a huge topic which I cannot tell this moment), and parent of this component doesn't get re-render, then it's expected that all lifecycle hooks won't get executed until the Action has been done.

That might be a huge effort to reduce re-render in a complex application written in Reactjs. But in a small application which in the sense that re-render is not too much bad impact to browser/webview. In this case, you are free to assume that these lifecycle hooks never get executed. But be careful side effect which may harm your application.